# Why do I have different root urls on different dev enviroments?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat8

Please forgive the ignorance here, I am not a pro and haven't coded in years.  I am trying to resurrect a Java-EE project I put on the shelf over 2 years ago and am running into a problem after setting up the development environment for the first time on this computer where none of the links are working and none of the images or icons are loading.  I have the site running on an old computer where things look fine.  The main different I can see is that the old site just has the root url "http://localhost:8080/" and the new site has the root url "http://localhost:8080/DoItRight/".  DoItRight is the project name.  See images below for visuals.

The components of my dev environment are:

- Java-EE
- Apache Tomcat 8.5
- Eclipse 4.9.0
- MySQL 8

I deployed the new site with the same files as the old one (using GitHub). So I am thinking it is a server setting, but it looks like server.xml is identical for each, but maybe I am missing something.

Any suggestions as to what is wrong with the new environment or what to do to fix it?  I don't even care if it is the same as the old one, I just want it to work!

[image: New Environment]

[image: Old Environment]

Comment: Just check web.xml for the path + check servlet.xml as there might be different root

Comment: Can you be more specific about the path in web.xml.  As far as I can tell they are the same but it a long file, so maybe this is the wrong part. <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>   
    
    Also, I can't find a servlet.xml anywhere

Comment: Maybe different Tomcats? With the same codebase both evns should work with `/DoItRight/` and additionally `/` could be handled as well with the configuration of defaul application. Maybe you got apache/nginx as proxy on one environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I learned that I just had to clean my Tomcat deployment!  Also, I had to change the context root setting in the Web Project Settings page to only be a forward slash.  I had done that part before, but didn't clean the server.